# how to ignore tags in many XML files using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a lot of xml files with lots of text in them. This text I need to do lower case and remove punctuation. 
BUT I dont know how to say using python that I want it to ignore all the tags.

I found an xml parser called ElementTree and I have a regex to find tags : 
`pattern = re.compile ('<[^<]*?>')`

I tested it and it gives me only the text in the first tag  (there are many tags named ). Why?

I test in a string to make a different test so to get all the tags:

```py
text = "<root> <test>aaaaaaa </test> <test2> bbbbbbbbb </test2> </root> <root> <test3> cccccc </test3> <test4> ddddd </test4> </root>"
pattern = re.compile ('<[^<]*?>')
tmp = pattern.findall(content, re.DOTALL)
```

and it gives me:

```py
['</test>', '<test2>', '</test2>', '</root>', '<root>', '<test3>', '</test3>', '<test4>', '</test4>', '</root>']
```

why not `<root> <test>` also?

Comment: Your XML doesn't appear to be valid. You have <root> twice.

Comment: my point was to show that in my xml files there are many <DOC> tags and I get the text only until the first one with this error:
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 173, column 0
line 173 is in xml file where the second <DOC> begins.

Comment: That error could be because the XML file has special characters or a particular encoding.

Answer (score 7):

You don't actually appear to be using ElementTree.

[Here](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is an example of how to use ElementTree

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

You could use recursion to run all the tags through a function to clean them up:

```py
def clean_tag(tag):
    for child in tag:
        clean_tag(child)
    if tag.text != None:
        # add your code to do lowercase and punctuation here
        tag.text = tag.text.lower()

clean_tag(tree.getroot())
clean_xml = ET.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you say "to clean them up" you mean remove them? Because I don't want to remove them. I just want it to ignore them and do the lowercase+rmv punct to the text. I need those tags so that I do another process later.

Comment: By "clean" I meant converting the text to lowercase, removing punctuation.